# Unity 2d jumping horizontally not always works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So i have this code for player movement in Unity:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float jumpingHorizontal;
    private float speed = 8f;
    private float jumpingPower = 0f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    private bool isJumping = false;

    private float maxJumpingPower = 10f;

    private float jumpingDelta = 0f;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    void Update()
    {
        jumpingHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (!isJumping) {
            horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        } else {
            horizontal = 0;
        } 

        if ((Time.time - jumpingDelta)*maxJumpingPower > maxJumpingPower && isJumping ) {
            jumpingPower = maxJumpingPower;
            // jumpingHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            Debug.Log("JumpingPowerFull" + jumpingPower);
            Debug.Log("JumpingHorizontalFull" + jumpingHorizontal);
            Jump();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && IsGrounded())
        {
            jumpingDelta = Time.time;
            isJumping = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && IsGrounded() && isJumping)
        {
                    
            jumpingDelta = Time.time - jumpingDelta;
            jumpingPower = maxJumpingPower * jumpingDelta;
            Debug.Log("JumpingPower:" + jumpingPower);
            Jump();
        }

        Flip();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (IsGrounded()) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }


    }

    

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }


    private bool IsInAir()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.5f, groundLayer);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {   
        if (!IsGrounded()) {
            return;
        } 
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        jumpingHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(jumpingHorizontal * speed, jumpingPower * 100f));
        jumpingPower = 0f;
        isJumping = false;
        Debug.Log("JumpingHorizontal" + jumpingHorizontal);
    }   
}
```

and i'm trying to make the height of jump depend on time spent holding space but when i test it, it sometimes doesnt work as intended and jumping horizontally doesnt work and player just jumps straight up (most of the times it works as intended but it mostly happens when i press space and arrow (horizontal movement key) it jumps straight)

i basically tried everythink i could think of like: passing parameter to jump which tells the code which side should it jump (input.getaxisraw("horizontal")) but worked the same way and also i tried doing more helpful variables but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to C# so I could be very wrong. Nonetheless, here are my hypotheses.

First, in if (isJumping), horizontal is equal to 0. Could explain the issue of a lack of horizontal movement when jumping.

Second, try moving the code to get the jumping input (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) inside the if condition where you check if the player is jumping. Doing so, horizontal input won't affect the player's movement while jumping.

Lastly, in the Jump() method, try removing the line jumpingHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");. Horizontal jumping input was obtained in the Update() method, so there is no need to get it again in the Jump() method.

Hope I could be of some help. Cheers!